# Bootstrap Fixed Navbar Links to stay on same line as Brand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Before Start, I have searched for the last few hours, found several replies but none that fixed this issue.

I only have one link, and I have a fixed to top navbar. I want the Link to stay on the same line as the Brand in mobile/smaller screens.

Right now on mobile (Ref image below):

[image]

I have tried floating it right to see if that helped, but it didn't.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topFixedNavbar1">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">1 Link Only<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: inline-block!important;
}

.navbar-nav>li, .navbar-nav {
  float: left !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Phil, Could you give the code in fiddle or the like of the page which having issue!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to delete `collapse navbar-collapse` classes and use a custom class. You can name it `custom-navbar-nav`. Finally, add the CSS showed here. If you definitely want your link on the top, you need to use media queries.

```css
.navbar-header {
  display: inline-block;
}

.custom-navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></div>
       <div class="custom-navbar-nav">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="#">1 Link Only<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```